# Sort NSArray with NSDate object into NSDictionary by month

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am building a `UITableView` and would like to group by month so that I can have those strings as my section headers, e.g.:

```
February 2013
- Item 1
- Item 2

January 2013
- Item 1
- Item 2
```

I have an `NSArray` which has custom objects that have a pubDate property that is an `NSDate`.

How can I use that `NSDate` object to group my custom objects into a `NSDictionary` by month?

Comment: You can sort the date array quite simply (if it is purely NSDate objects) using the built-in array sort routines.  Then "walk" through the array and note when a new month starts, adding the appropriate month header.

Comment: No, the array is filled with custom objects with one of the properties being an `NSDate`.

Comment: Then it requires describing the path to the date through one of the several array sort methods.  Only marginally more complicated.

Comment: @NicHubbard Did you got Answer? My Requirement is same as you.Please let me know how can i achieve result like your Question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sort array like this

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [yourArrayOfCustomObjects sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        NSDate *firstDate = [(YourCustomObject*)obj1 pubDate];
        NSDate *secondDate = [(YourCustomObject*)obj2 pubDate];
        return [firstDate compare:secondDate];        

    }];
```

// Now a simple iteration and you can determine all same month entries.

// Code is not complete just for illustration purpose.

// You have to handle Year change as well.

```
int curMonth = 0;
int prevMonth = 0;
foreach(CustomObject *obj in sortedArray)
{
   NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:obj.pubDate];
   prevMonth = curMonth; 
   curMonth = components.month;
   if(prevMonth != 0 && curMonth != prevMonth)
   {
      //Month Changed
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`NSDateComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003470). If you convert your dates to date components:

```
[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit) fromDate:date]
```

then you'll have objects you can very easily compare for equality.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this question was missing answer from Ole Begemann, however this is a link (and I'm not able to post a comment < repo) I'm giving an answer to this question,

If someone still looking for some elegant solution, check this out,

http://oleb.net/blog/2011/12/tutorial-how-to-sort-and-group-uitableview-by-date/